change php version and execute file inside a php script
I have a bat file looks like below
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v8.1.8\
php C:\websites\user1\batchscripts\test_batch.php  

And its run good.
I need to run the batchscripts\test_batch.php in my php script. I tried like
$command = "php C:\websites\user1\batchscripts\test_batch.php  ";
system("cd C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v8.1.8\php.exe ".$command);

But this not worked. I tried with both exec and system functions.
In a button click I need to run this file(batchscripts\test_batch.php) .
My current php version is 5.3. But to run the batchscript I need php 8.1.8. Thats why I am using PHP\v8.1.8\ in my code.
